Using OnModelCreating ModelBuilder how can I restrict an int attribute range?
If I have a class with 2 attributes
class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Score {get; set;}
}

When I use the ModelBuilder for example I can restrict the length of the name string like this.
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...
    modelBuilder.Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(64);
}

Is there a way to restrict the the int attribute to only be between 0 and 1200?
Is it even something that is possible or is the best approach to use a smaller size int and be limited to the standard size of that data type?

You can use Entity Properties like this (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt):
class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    [Range(1, 1200)]
    public int Score {get; set;}
}

This will only allow scores between 1 and 1200. I hope this is what you want.
